# Not able to get attached document in workflow task consistently

Tags: workflow, alfresco, alfresco-share

I am using Alfresco Community 5.1.0 and observing a strange behavior in workflow task. When I open a task to complete which contains attached document as packageItems. I am not able to see that document instead I am seeing a Select button. But when I refresh a page, I am able to see attached document. After carefully observing this behavior I found that, the task edit page is getting rendered first then packageItems which contains attached is rendered. I am not sure whether this is a cause for not getting documents in packageItems or it is occurring because of any other reason. It would be appreciable any would help me in solving this problem.

I am attaching two screenshots which would help to understand this problem better

1:- Not found document in task

2:- Able to see document after refreshing the page

[image: Not found document in task]

[image: Able to see document after refreshing a page]

Comment: Please share your specific Alfresco version, specific browser version, and whether or not you've deployed any customizations to your Share install.

Comment: I am using Alfresco Community 5.1.0 and we have tested it in Chrome  Version 58.0.3029.110 (64-bit), Mozilla Firefox 53.0 (32-bit), and also in Microsoft Edge browser. I have created some custom workflows but above mentioned behavior can also be found on OOTB workflows.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this with Alfresco Community 5.1.g (201605-GA) on macOS 10.12.5 and Firefox 53.0.3 (64-bit) and out-of-the-box workflows. Is the rest of your installation functioning normally, especially search?

Comment: yes, search is working properly, I have tested it in aws deployment server by searching a word from docx file and I got the results.But the above mentioned problem is still same. Same as like you I have also tested in my local machine consisting windows 10 and alfresco community 5.1.0 and it is working fine and in my local server I am getting document everytime in workflow tasks.